# What is this hazy tunnel vision?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm playing Minecraft 1.14.4. Occasionally, a radial fog or hazy tunnel vision will begin to develop. Reloading the world doesn't get rid of it. Dying does remove it. What is this?

[image]

Comment: Are you playing with mods?

Comment: Yes, they are. And without more information, it could be pretty much anything, because mods can change everything about the game.

Comment: Please clarify your question and include more information, especially which mods you have installed.